# запятая перед "как" Нужна ли?

Tags: пунктуация

Он получил освобождение, но оковы так и хранил всю жизнь, как символ предательства.  Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

Answer (score 1):

*Он получил освобождение, но оковы так и хранил всю жизнь **как символ предательства***.

Запятая не ставится, оборот с союзом КАК не обособляется, так как имеет значение "в качестве, рассматривая, приравнивая".

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как не выделяется запятыми:

2) если основное значение оборота — приравнивание или отождествление: …Ты любил меня как собственность, как источник радостей, тревог и печалей (Л.)